# Column level parsing in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

Currently I am working with 20M records with 5 columns. My data frame looks like -

```
tran_id   id       code
123        1    1759@1@83@0#1362@0.2600@25.7400@2.8600#1094@1@129.6@14.4
254        1    1356@0.4950@26.7300@2.9700
831        2    1354@1.78@35.244@3.916#1101@2@40@0#1108@2@30@0
732        5    1430@1@19.35@2.15#1431@3@245.62@60.29#1074@12@385.2@58.8#1109
141        2    1809@8@75.34@292.66#1816@4@24.56@95.44#1076@47@510.89@1110.61
```

Desired output -

```
id       new_code
1        1759
1        1362
1        1094
1        1356
2        1354
2        1101
2        1108
5        1430
5        1431
5        1074
5        1109
2        1809
2        1816
2        1076
```

What I have done so far -

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dd= pd.DataFrame({'col' : d["code"].apply(lambda x: re.split('[#  @ ]', x))})
dd.head()    
s = dd['col'].str[:]
dd= pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist())
dd.head()

cols = range(len(list(dd)))
num_cols = len(list(dd))
new_cols = ['col' + str(i) for i in cols]
dd.columns = new_cols[:num_cols]
```

Just remember the size of the data is huge...20 million.Can't do any looping.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for extract integers with length 4 between separators:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/55096994/2901002
s = df['code'].str.findall(r'(?<![^#])\d{4}(?![^@])')
#alternative
#s = df['code'].str.replace('[#@]', ' ').str.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d{4}(?!\S)')
```

And then create new DataFrame by [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and flaten by `chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : df['id'].values.repeat(s.str.len()),
    'new_code' : list(chain.from_iterable(s.tolist()))
})
print (df)
    id new_code
0    1     1759
1    1     1362
2    1     1094
3    1     1356
4    2     1354
5    2     1101
6    2     1108
7    5     1430
8    5     1431
9    5     1074
10   5     1109
11   2     1809
12   2     1816
13   2     1076
```

Comment: got this error TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-95b82e503210> in <module>
      1 df = pd.DataFrame({
----> 2     'id' : df['id'].values.repeat(s.str.len()),
      3     'new_code' : list(chain.from_iterable(s.tolist()))
      4 })
      5 

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: @NikitaAgarwal - How working change `s.str.len()` to `s.str.len().astype(np.int64)` ?

Comment: I am not changing anything..my code is given below - df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : df['id'].values.repeat(s.str.len()),
    'new_code' : list(chain.from_iterable(s.tolist()))
})

df.head(20)

Currently I am working on full dataset...is this a reason?some of the values are in different format

Comment: So same error if use `df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : df['id'].values.repeat(s.str.len().astype(np.int64)), 'new_code' : list(chain.from_iterable(s.tolist())) })` ?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with a different regex pattern:

```
(df.set_index('id').code.str.extractall(r'(?:[^\.]|^)(?P<new_code>\d{4})')
 .reset_index(0)
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

[out]

```
    id new_code
0    1     1759
1    1     1362
2    1     1094
3    1     1356
4    2     1354
5    2     1101
6    2     1108
7    5     1430
8    5     1431
9    5     1074
10   5     1109
11   2     1809
12   2     1816
13   2     1076
14   2     1110
```