# Extract integers with specific length between separators

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

Given a list of strings like:

```
L = ['1759@1@83@0#1362@0.2600@25.7400@2.8600#1094@1@129.6@14.4', 
     '1356@0.4950@26.7300@2.9700', 
     '1354@1.78@35.244@3.916#1101@2@40@0#1108@2@30@0',
     '1430@1@19.35@2.15#1431@3@245.62@60.29#1074@12@385.2@58.8#1109',
     '1809@8@75.34@292.66#1816@4@24.56@95.44#1076@47@510.89@1110.61']
```

I need to extract all integers with length 4 between separators `#` or `@`, and also extract the first and last integers. No floats.

My solution is a bit overcomplicated - replace with space and then applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765927/2901002) solution:

```
pat = r'(?<!\S)\d{4}(?!\S)'
out = [re.findall(pat, re.sub('[#@]', ' ', x)) for x in L]
print (out)
"""
[['1759', '1362', '1094'], 
 ['1356'], 
 ['1354', '1101', '1108'], 
 ['1430', '1431', '1074', '1109'], 
 ['1809', '1816', '1076']]
"""
```

Is it possible to change the regex for not using `re.sub` necessarily for replace? Is there another solution with better performance?

Comment: Your current code results in integers at the edges of the string being matched too, despite those integers lacking at least one separator, is that desirable?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - good question, Yes, I need first and last 4 length integers if exist

Comment: By new requirement, so do you want `1110` to be matched too?

Comment: @revo - expected output is `out`, last `1110.61` is not matched, because float

Comment: So what is wrong with a simple re `(?<![^#])\d{4}(?![^@])`?

Comment: See it here https://ideone.com/X50Hvm

Comment: If you had a number with trailing decimal but no decimal digits like `1110.`, would you want it included/excluded/don't-care?

Comment: @anky_91 - ya, no problem...

Comment: @anky_91 - absolutely no, notnecessary ask :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow first and last occurrences that has no leading or trailing separator you could use negative lookarounds:

```
(?<![^#])\d{4}(?![^@])
```

`(?<![^#])` is a *near* synonym for `(?:^|#)`. The same applies for the negative lookahead.

See live [demo here](https://ideone.com/X50Hvm)

Answer (score 3):

**Interesting problem!**

This can be easily tackled with the concepts of lookahead & lookbehind.

**INPUT**

```
pattern = "(?<!\.)(?<=[#@])\d{4}|(?<!\.)\d{4}(?=[@#])"
out = [re.findall(pattern, x) for x in L]
print (out)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['1759', '1362', '1094', '1234'],
 ['1356'],
 ['1354', '1101', '1108'],
 ['1430', '1431', '1074', '1109'],
 ['1809', '1816', '1076', '1110']]
```

**EXPLANATION**

The above *pattern* is a combination of two separate patterns separated by an *|* (OR operator).

```
pattern_1 = "(?<!\.)(?<=[#@])\d{4}"
\d{4}     --- Extract exactly 4 digits
(?<!\.)   --- The 4 digits must not be preceded by a period(.) NEGATIVE LOOKBEHIND
(?<=[#@]) --- The 4 digits must be preceded by a hashtag(#) or at(@) POSITIVE LOOKBEHIND

pattern_2 = "(?<!\.)\d{4}(?=[@#])"
\d{4}     --- Extract exactly 4 digits
(?<!\.)   --- The 4 digits must not be preceded by a period(.) NEGATIVE LOOKBEHIND
(?=[@#]   --- The 4 digits must be followed by a hashtag(#) or at(@) POSITIVE LOOKAHEAD
```

To better understand these concepts, [click here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complex list comprehension without using regex if you consider the integers of length 4 without the starting `#` or ending `@` too :

```
[[n for o in p for n in o] for p in [[[m for m in k.split("@") if m.isdigit() and str(int(m))==m and len(m) ==4] for k in j.split("#")] for j in L]]
```

**Output** :

```
[['1759', '1362', '1094'], ['1356'], ['1354', '1101', '1108'], ['1430', '1431', '1074', '1109'], ['1809', '1816', '1076']]
```